# How do I import a shared module (with Angular Material) to test Angular applications?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-test

I'm trying to start creating tests for an Angular sample application that also uses Angular Material and Angular Flex layout.

Within my app, I'm already using a shared module to import all the Angular Material components. It goes like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, MatCardModule,
    MatDatepickerModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule,
    MatTabsModule, MatNativeDateModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, MatCardModule,
    MatDatepickerModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule,
    MatTabsModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

When I first ran `ng test` every component would fail the basic creation test. Most certainly the messages mentioned Angular Material tags. So, I tried this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AccountComponent } from './account.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material.module';

describe('AccountComponent', () => {
  let component: AccountComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AccountComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AccountComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        MaterialModule
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AccountComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This test, however, did not pass. However, I tried importing the modules manually, one after the other as the error messages stated:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AccountComponent } from './account.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';

describe('AccountComponent', () => {
  let component: AccountComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AccountComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AccountComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatCardModule
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AccountComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

To my surprise, the test now passes. And I really can't figure why.

Is there anyway I can import a shared module when testing just like I do in the regular application?

Comment: Can you please include the error message you're getting in the first case?

Comment: @yurzui you actually helped me find the answer with such a simple question. Thank you. Answer below. And I feel embarassed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to thank @yurzui on this one. He requested the error message I was getting on my test.

As it turns out, I wasn't really paying attention to the message and I noticed when copying to post here. The error message did mentioned an unknown tag which I know is from Angular Material. However, just below it was mentioning the problem in a different component.

The catch here is that `AccountComponent` is a tabbed page which displays another two components which on the testing module did not import the material module. I feel embarassed.